# Design is Breaking (Layout ot taking the available width)

Tags: html, css

Due to the certain reason I have eliminated the content from the main section here, and see the design is breaking.

Here is the HTML of the main section →

```
<div class="main col">
        
</div>
```

The **CSS** of the main-sidebar is like this →

```
.main-sidebar {
    /*background: #323232;*/
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 2.127659574468%;
    color:black;
}
```

And the CSS of the content area is like this →

```
.main {
background: #ffffff;
width:67.8%;
color: #000000;
```

}

You can see that the width in percentage is defined for both the main-sidebar and the main content area. The mathematics of width distribution is like this →

## 67.8% + 30% + Remaining is the margin/padding  = 100%

Then **why** (even though we do not have the content in the main section) the designs breaks, see for example [here](http://html.ankishpost.com/front-page.html).

And when there is a content the [design works flawlessly.](http://html.ankishpost.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.content` container is set as `display: table;` thus it won't fill the whole width of its own container. Remove the `display: table;` property or set explicitly the width to 100% and that should fix the layout.

Answer (score 1):

** use this css code **

```
   .content {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }
```